# Perl regular expression is not matching with \w+

Tags: regex, perl, match

I am trying to extract some data from scalar variable which are database values:

Copying my code here

```
$data = "header1        header2     header3     header4     header5 
-------------------------------------------------------
data1           1a          1b          1c          1d
data2           2a          2b          2c          2d
data3           3a          3b          3c          3d
(3 rows affected)";

if ($data =~ /header5\s+[\-|\s+]*(\w*)[^(]*/){
    print $1;
    print "inside if\n";
}
else {
    print "else part\n";   
}
```

Here I want to take out below data:

```
data1           1a          1b          1c          1d
data2           2a          2b          2c          2d
data3           3a          3b          3c          3d
```

For that I have used a regular expression.

But here I could see `$1` prints `data1` instead of values till last.

How can I have all the (3 rows of data) data in `$1`? Please help with the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(\w*)` matches 0 or more word chars, and that is `data1` at the location where the regex finds this match. The rest of the text up to `(` is not captured into this group.

Use

```
/header5\s[-\s]*([^(]*)/
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KUvIni)

**Pattern details**

- `header5` - a literal string of text
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[-\s]*` - 0 or more hyphens or whitespaces
- `([^(]*)` - Group 1 (`$1` contents): 0 or more chars other than `(`.